# Issue with SharePoint list Item's Undo Checkout

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, csom, check-out

I am working on custom solution.

If end user undo checkout for an item in Doc. Library, then file gets undo but "version history gets overwrite and modify by will be user who did this undo". How to protect this overwrite to version history? I am using CSOM.

```
item.File.UndoCheckOut();
```

Comment: Can you check if something has been written in your code for this behavior because I have done the same thing and  it's not overwriting the version history. Or maybe you can post the whole code snippet here that you are using to "Discard Checkout" the pages.

Comment: As I understand, the versions history will be generated after the file rechecked in, if in your code, never checked in files until UndoCheckOut, it will not generate the new version history, and also share your complete code please.